# How to bind the content of the buttons with list of values in other xaml page?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-7

Hi I want write a  game applications, for that reason I have three user controls each user control is having number of buttons. Say Usercontrol1 having 5 buttons Usercontrol2 having 6 buttons and so on...

Now in the MainPage.xaml I have a canvas called GameCanvas, and at runtime depends upon the difficulty level, I am populating one usercontrol then in the next level another one and so on, like `GameCanvas.Children.Add(uc1);` etc.

Now in the MainPage I have a listofValues

```
List<int> listValues = new List<int>();
```

which in the constructor I am filling up, so first time the `listOfValues` holds 5 numbers, and this 5 numbers I want to display as Content of the five Buttons in `userControl1`.

In the next level I will generate 6 numbers of `listOfNumbers` and want to show the UserControl2 to the user and fill the 6 Buttons content as this 6 numbers. Ay idea how do I do it?

In the constructor of the `GamePage`

I have created

```
uc1 = new userControl1();
uc2= new userControl12();
```

and when in the constructor when first time I am loading

`GameCanvas.Children.Add(uc1);`

I am getting Buttons content as null values. 
But how do I fill the `Buttons` content of the `UserControl1` with the values of the listValues of GamePage?

Comment: Take a look at [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.aspx).  It allows you to supply its ItemsSource a collection and with the ItemTemplate, create a single look for each item in the collection.

Comment: @blandau, thanks but any idea how do I implement that? items collection will be in the MainPage or in the individual userControl?

Comment: @blandau thanks for yoru  input, I managed the requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution of the problem I raised in this question. I researched something and get help from one of the Microsoft tech guy and implemented the same to my problem. Due to the privacy issue with the code I will just give a general outline of how I resolve the issue.

My problem was one MainPage.xaml page another userControl1.xaml page, usercontrol is having some buttons and the content of the buttons will be some listValues those are generated in the MainPage.xaml.cs

Now in the usercontrol I have written a code

```
<Grid>
    <Button Content="{Binding Path=ListOfValues[0]}" Margin="109,140,101,109" />
    <Button Content="{Binding Path=ListOfValues[1]}" Margin="18,86,212,162"   />
    <Button Content="{Binding Path=ListOfValues[2]}" Margin="218,206,12,43"   />
</Grid>
```

and UserControl DataContext as

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindow  />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

Where "local" is your apps name. There won't be any code behind in the UserControl.

Now in the MainPage.xaml

```
<Grid Loaded="Grid_Loaded" >
    <Canvas x:Name="GameCanvas" Margin="12,52,98,26" />
</Grid>
```

and in the code Behind part, this part is important.

First define a property

```
public List<int> ListOfValues
{
   //with get, set and INotifyPropertyChanged implemented.
}
```

in the constructor of the MainPage write

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
```

And in the MainPage_Loaded code behind

```
        private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _listofValues.Add(1);
        _listofValues.Add(2);
        _listofValues.Add(3);

        var uc1 = new UserControl1(); // 
        uc1.DataContext = this;
        GameCanvas.Children.Add(uc1);
    }
```

Run the application. You can see that all the buttons Content is ListOfValues in the same order.

It's a simple applications and no MVVM, so anybody if Implementing MVVM with Command binding and write an updated answer would be good. Hope it will help many users who would have similar kind of requirements.